# PyShp ASCII encoding error

Tags: python-2.7, ascii, encoding, pyshp, utf-8

I want to filter a set of Point Shapefiles using PyShp. That works fine with one of the file sets (one point shapefile) but throws an error for another set that states:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As far as I understand that means it tries to encode the input (because it works with the other files) in ASCII but can't. How do I change the encoding to UTF-8? Just in case, here is my shapefile.reader:

```
sf = shapefile.Reader(pfad)
```

Whereas "pfad" is user input for the location of the file. Any ideas?

Edit:
To rule out any shapefile.reader issues I append the code from the PyShp for the reader class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.shp = None
    self.shx = None
    self.dbf = None
    self.shapeName = "Not specified"
    self._offsets = []
    self.shpLength = None
    self.numRecords = None
    self.fields = []
    self.__dbfHdrLength = 0
    # See if a shapefile name was passed as an argument
    if len(args) > 0:
        if is_string(args[0]):
            self.load(args[0])
            return
    if "shp" in kwargs.keys():
        if hasattr(kwargs["shp"], "read"):
            self.shp = kwargs["shp"]
            if hasattr(self.shp, "seek"):
                self.shp.seek(0)
        if "shx" in kwargs.keys():
            if hasattr(kwargs["shx"], "read"):
                self.shx = kwargs["shx"]
                if hasattr(self.shx, "seek"):
                    self.shx.seek(0)
    if "dbf" in kwargs.keys():
        if hasattr(kwargs["dbf"], "read"):
            self.dbf = kwargs["dbf"]
            if hasattr(self.dbf, "seek"):
                self.dbf.seek(0)
    if self.shp or self.dbf:        
        self.load()
    else:
        raise ShapefileException("Shapefile Reader requires a shapefile or file-like object.")
```

Edit 2: Error log including a traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2898, in run_code
self.showtraceback()

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1824, in showtraceback
value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1406, in structured_traceback
self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1323, in structured_traceback
self, etype, value, elist, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 644, in structured_traceback
out_list.extend(self._format_list(elist))

File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 694, in _format_list
Colors.Normal)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: This seems like a pure Python issue, not a GIS-centric one, but you haven't provided enough code to tell for sure.

Comment: Yes, I think so, too. Also I would say, that the error comes from the incoming data, ad other files work. Maybe, if that data could be decoded with utf-8 instead of ascii it would work.

Comment: If you provide a code snippet and the complete error message (which includes a traceback), it will be easier to determine if this is a bug report for pyshp or something with which we can help. A screenshot that shows whether the offending data is in the field names or record data would also be useful.

Comment: What is `pfad`  (`shapefile.Reader(pfad)` )?

Comment: It is user input. So the user can decide where the file to work on is located. `pfad = input("Wie lautet der Pfad der zu bearbeitenden Datei ?")` `sf = shapefile.Reader(pfad)`